# python tkinter adding multiple combobox value display problem

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

This is the the whole code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def click():
    global totalvalues
    if combo_impact.get()and combo_likelihood.get() != '':
        totalvalues= int(combo_impact.get()) + int(combo_likelihood.get())

    total.configure(text="Risk score : " + str(totalvalues))



def main():
    

    impactDict = {'Catstrophic': 5, 'Severe': 4, 'Major': 3, 'Moderate': 2, 'Minor':1}
    likelihoodDict = {'Almost Certain': 5, 'likely': 4, 'probable': 3, 'unlikely': 2, 'rare':1}

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("TEST Form")
    root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')

    tk.Label(root, text='legal Risk Impact', bd=3, bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=0)
    var_impact = tk.StringVar()
    combo_impact = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(impactDict.keys()), justify="center", textvariable=var_impact)
    combo_impact.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: impact_level.config(text=impactDict[var_impact.get()]))
    combo_impact.grid(row=0, column=1)
    combo_impact.current(0)

    impact_level = tk.Label(root, text="", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white')
    impact_level.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

    tk.Label(root, text='Legal risk Likelihood', bd=3, bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white').grid(row=1, column=0)
    var_likelihood = tk.StringVar()
    combo_likelihood = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(likelihoodDict.keys()), justify="center", textvariable=var_likelihood)
    combo_likelihood.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: likelihood_level.config(text=likelihoodDict[var_likelihood.get()]))
    combo_likelihood.grid(row=1, column=1)
    combo_likelihood.current(0)

    likelihood_level = tk.Label(root, text="Not Selected", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white')
    likelihood_level.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

    totalvalues = 'None'
    total = tk.Label(root,text = "", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white' )
    total.grid(row=2, column = 2, padx=20, pady=10)

    calculate=tk.Button(root,text='Rate', command=click).grid(column=3,row=3)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should be using `global combo_impact, combo_likelihood, impactDict, likelihoodDict, total` inside `main()`, then `totalvalues= int(impactDict[combo_impact.get()]) + int(likelihoodDict[combo_likelihood.get()])`, you need to index the dictionary with the fetched values, like so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I want to code> i have resolved the issue in non-pytonic way using too long codes. Although I have tried to bring my idea into some glitter of hope. I am not satisfied with my code. Because it is not unprofessional. For the purpose of education, I am sharing the resolved non-pythonic code from my trial and error. It can be a good education tool for some instructors:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
```

def click(*args):

```
global totalvalues
global combo_impact
global combo_likelihood
global impactDict
global likelihoodDict
global total
global risk_level
global x
global y
global negligiblelabel2
global negligiblelabel3
global negligiblelabel1
global lowlabel1
global lowlabel2
global lowlabel3
global lowlabel4
global lowlabel5
global mediumlabel1
global mediumlabel2
global mediumlabel3
global mediumlabel4
global mediumlabel5
global mediumlabel6
global mediumlabel7
global highlabel1
global highlabel2
global highlabel3
global highlabel4
global extremelabel1
global extremelabel2
global extremelabel3
global extremelabel4
global extremelabel5
global extremelabel6


if combo_impact.get()and combo_likelihood.get() != '':
    totalvalues= int(impactDict[combo_impact.get()]) * int(likelihoodDict[combo_likelihood.get()])
    
total.configure(text="Risk score : " + str(totalvalues))

x = int(impactDict[combo_impact.get()])
y = int(likelihoodDict[combo_likelihood.get()])

if x == 1 and y==1:
    negligiblelabel2.configure(text="Negligible risk")

elif x == 1 and y==2:
    negligiblelabel3.configure(text="Negligible risk")
elif x == 2 and y==1:
    negligiblelabel1.configure(text="Negligible risk")
elif x == 1 and y==3:
    lowlabel4.configure(text="Low risk")
elif x == 3 and y==1:
    lowlabel2.configure(text="Low risk")
elif x == 1 and y==4:
    lowlabel5.configure(text="Low risk")
elif x == 4 and y==1:
    lowlabel1.configure(text="Low risk")
elif x == 2 and y==2:
    lowlabel3.configure(text="Low risk")
elif x == 2 and y==3:
    mediumlabel5.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 3 and y==2:
    mediumlabel3.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 2 and y==4:
    mediumlabel6.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 4 and y==2:
    mediumlabel2.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 3 and y==3:
    mediumlabel4.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 1 and y==5:
    mediumlabel7.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 5 and y==1:
    mediumlabel1.configure(text="Medium risk")
elif x == 2 and y==5:
    highlabel4.configure(text = "High risk") 
elif x == 5 and y==2:
    highlabel1.configure(text = "High risk")
elif x == 3 and y==4:
    highlabel3.configure(text = "High risk")
elif x == 4 and y==3:
    highlabel2.configure(text = "High risk")
elif x == 3 and y==5:
    extremelabel6.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
elif x == 5 and y==3:
    extremelabel1.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
elif x == 4 and y ==4:
    extremelabel3.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
elif x == 4 and y==5:
    extremelabel5.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
elif x == 5 and y==4:
    extremelabel2.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
elif x == 5 and y==5:
    extremelabel4.configure(text= "Extreme risk")
else:
    print('wrong input')
```

def main():
global combo_impact
global combo_likelihood
global impactDict
global likelihoodDict
global total
global risk_level
global negligiblelabel2
global negligiblelabel1
global negligiblelabel3
global lowlabel1
global lowlabel2
global lowlabel3
global lowlabel4
global lowlabel5
global mediumlabel1
global mediumlabel2
global mediumlabel3
global mediumlabel4
global mediumlabel5
global mediumlabel6
global mediumlabel7
global highlabel1
global highlabel2
global highlabel3
global highlabel4
global extremelabel1
global extremelabel2
global extremelabel3
global extremelabel4
global extremelabel5
global extremelabel6

```
impactDict = {'Catstrophic': 5, 'Severe': 4, 'Major': 3, 'Moderate': 2, 'Minor':1}
likelihoodDict = {'Almost Certain': 5, 'likely': 4, 'possible': 3, 'unlikely': 2, 'rare':1}

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TEST Form")
root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')

tk.Label(root, text='legal Risk Impact', bd=3, bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white').grid(row=0, column=0)
var_impact = tk.StringVar()
combo_impact = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(impactDict.keys()), justify="center", textvariable=var_impact)
combo_impact.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: impact_level.config(text=impactDict[var_impact.get()]))
combo_impact.grid(row=0, column=1)
combo_impact.current(0)

impact_level = tk.Label(root, text="", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white')
impact_level.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

tk.Label(root, text='Legal risk Likelihood', bd=3, bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white').grid(row=1, column=0)
var_likelihood = tk.StringVar()
combo_likelihood = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(likelihoodDict.keys()), justify="center", textvariable=var_likelihood)
combo_likelihood.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: likelihood_level.config(text=likelihoodDict[var_likelihood.get()]))
combo_likelihood.grid(row=1, column=1)
combo_likelihood.current(0)

likelihood_level = tk.Label(root, text="", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white')
likelihood_level.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)

totalvalues = 'None'
total = tk.Label(root,text = "", bg='Dodgerblue4', fg='white' )
total.grid(row=2, column = 1, padx=20, pady=10)

calculate=tk.Button(root,width = 10, text='Rate', command=click).grid(column=0,row=2, padx=1, pady=1)

matrixframe = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground='#292A2E', bd=1)
matrixframe.grid(row=3, column = 3, padx=20, pady=10)
impactlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Impact", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
impactlabel.grid(row=0, column = 0)
impactlabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Impact", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
impactlabel1.grid(row=1, column = 0)
impactlabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Impact", bg='#384455', fg='white')
impactlabel2.grid(row=2, column = 0)
impactlabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Impact", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
impactlabel3.grid(row=3, column = 0)
impactlabel4 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Impact", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
impactlabel4.grid(row=4, column = 0)
catstrophiclabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 12, text = "Catstrophic", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
catstrophiclabel.grid(row=0, column = 1)
severelabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 12, text = "Severe", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
severelabel.grid(row=1, column = 1)
majorlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 12, text = "Major", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
majorlabel.grid(row=2, column = 1)
moderatelabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 12, text = "Moderate", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
moderatelabel.grid(row=3, column = 1)
minorlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 12, text = "Minor", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
minorlabel.grid(row=4, column = 1)
mediumlabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel1.grid(row=0, column = 2)
lowlabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#B5ED46', fg='black')
lowlabel1.grid(row=1, column = 2)
lowlabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#B5ED46', fg='black')
lowlabel2.grid(row=2, column = 2)
negligiblelabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#00B050', fg='black')
negligiblelabel1.grid(row=3, column = 2)
negligiblelabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#00B050', fg='black')
negligiblelabel2.grid(row=4, column = 2)
highlabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFC000', fg='black')
highlabel1.grid(row=0, column = 3)
mediumlabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel2.grid(row=1, column = 3)
mediumlabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel3.grid(row=2, column = 3)
lowlabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#B5ED46', fg='black')
lowlabel3.grid(row=3, column = 3)
negligiblelabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#00B050', fg='black')
negligiblelabel3.grid(row=4, column = 3)
extremelabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel1.grid(row=0, column = 4)
highlabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFC000', fg='black')
highlabel2.grid(row=1, column = 4)
mediumlabel4 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel4.grid(row=2, column = 4)
mediumlabel5 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel5.grid(row=3, column = 4)
lowlabel4 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#B5ED46', fg='black')
lowlabel4.grid(row=4, column = 4)
extremelabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel2.grid(row=0, column = 5)
extremelabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel3.grid(row=1, column = 5)
highlabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFC000', fg='black')
highlabel3.grid(row=2, column = 5)
mediumlabel6 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel6.grid(row=3, column = 5)
lowlabel5 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#B5ED46', fg='black')
lowlabel5.grid(row=4, column = 5)
extremelabel4 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel4.grid(row=0, column = 6)
extremelabel5 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel5.grid(row=1, column = 6)
extremelabel6 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FF0000', fg='black')
extremelabel6.grid(row=2, column = 6)
highlabel4 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFC000', fg='black')
highlabel4.grid(row=3, column = 6)
mediumlabel7 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, relief = 'groove', text = "", bg='#FFFF00', fg='black')
mediumlabel7.grid(row=4, column = 6)
heatmaplabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Heat Map", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#384455')
heatmaplabel.grid(row=5, column = 0)
heatmaplabel1 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 12, text = "Heat Map", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#FFFFFF')
heatmaplabel1.grid(row=5, column = 1)
rarelabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 15, text = "Rare", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
rarelabel.grid(row=5, column = 2)
unlikelylabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 15, text = "Unlikely", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
unlikelylabel.grid(row=5, column = 3)
possiblelabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 15, text = "Possible", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
possiblelabel.grid(row=5, column = 4)
likelylabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 15, text = "Likely", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
likelylabel.grid(row=5, column = 5)
almostcertainlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, relief = 'groove', width = 15, text = "Almost certain", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='black')
almostcertainlabel.grid(row=5, column = 6)
heatmaplabel2 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 10, text = "Heat Map", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#FFFFFF')
heatmaplabel2.grid(row=6, column = 0)
heatmaplabel3 = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 12, text = "Heat Map", bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#FFFFFF')
heatmaplabel3.grid(row=6, column = 1)
likelihoodlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, text = "", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
likelihoodlabel.grid(row=6, column = 2)
likelihoodlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, text = "", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
likelihoodlabel.grid(row=6, column = 3)
likelihoodlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, text = "Likelihood", bg='#384455', fg='#FFFFFF')
likelihoodlabel.grid(row=6, column = 4)
likelihoodlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, text = "", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
likelihoodlabel.grid(row=6, column = 5)
likelihoodlabel = tk.Label(matrixframe, height= 5, width = 15, text = "", bg='#384455', fg='#384455')
likelihoodlabel.grid(row=6, column = 6)


root.mainloop()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()